# Geo Polygon generation Python for ecommerce coverage definition

Tags: python, coordinates, geospatial, polygon, geopy

I’m trying to write an algorithm in python to create automatically polygons (cluster of exagons maybe) that have same “fall to ground” orders in a certain amount of time (i have a quite huge amount of geo data about it order: DATE,latitude,longitude, product ordered)
I need it to assign proper coverage to stores managing the avg number of orders per sore according to given properties.
So I need to be able to define polygons with equal probability of being the place of an e-commerce order and later be able to cluster them around a store and merging intona single polygon

I have no clue on how to set up the process.

U have some suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generate a hexagonal grid, clip grid to the research area, aggregate point data using the Spatial Join/Spatial Index function or your custom metric for Hexagonal geometric grid.

To achieve this can use the `h3` and `geopandas` python library or the **GIS** software.
Result like this:

[image]

Advantages of using the Hexagonal grid:

- Finding neighbors is easier with the hexagonal grid. For a rectangular grid, we have 4
  neighbors N units away and N^2 apart in a hexagonal grid the distances are equal to
  each of the six neighbors.
- Hexagons reduce the sample bias due to the grid shape boundary effects, which is related to
  a low ratio of the circumference to the area of the hexagon (a circle would be best but cannot be used).
- Over a large area, the hexagonal grid will be less distorted due to the curvature of the earth than the grid rectangular.
- When comparing polygons with equal areas, each point inside the hexagon is closer to the center
  hexagon than a given point in a square or triangle with an equal area (this is due to more acute angles
  square and triangle in relation to the hexagon).

And more benefits…

When looking for the best place for business, it is also a good idea to do a neighborhood analysis. Result like this:

[image]